# Setting CRM User's Manager: Error UserNotInParentHierarchy

Tags: vbscript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I wrote a script (VBScript) to create/update CRM users based on an external MySQL database. Everything works great except for automatically setting the user's manager. In the MySQL database, each user has a unique ID and a reports_to field with the ID of his manager if any.

In the CRM, a custom field in the SystemUser table contains the unique user ID from the external table. This way, by looking at the external reports_to field I can link a CRM User to another. The worst part is that it actually works for some users, until it reaches one that brings an error: "The user is not in parent user's business hierarchy." Can someone explain me what this error is about ? I could not find any details or similar cases on the Internet.

I can manually set the Manager for this user in the CRM and it does not give me any error.

Here is my code:

```
Dim ManagerUser As New SystemUser
ManagerUser = GetUser("tld_id", clrint(User._reports_to), _serviceProxy)
If Not IsNothing(ManagerUser) Then
    Dim ManagerId As Guid = ManagerUser.Id
    Dim Manager = New SetParentSystemUserRequest
    Manager.ParentId = ManagerId
    Manager.UserId = _UserId
    Manager.KeepChildUsers = True
    _serviceProxy.Execute(Manager)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what it meant.

Some Business Units in the CRM are Parents from others. I was working with a DEV MySQL table (still test phase) that had unclean data. It resulted in some users having the wrong BU set.

Error was triggered when the manager belonged to a BU child from the user's one.